# Apache reverse proxy for IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I would like to know what are the options for using Apache's HTTP server as a reverse proxy for IIS7 (serving ASP.NET content under 3.5 .NET Framework).

For JBoss/Tomcat or any other Java Application Server, I will use [MOD_JK](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/), but I would like to know what are your experiences with IIS7. What connectors are there available (if any) and what are the pros and cons of each one.

Thanks a lot. Great site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and configure it as reverse proxy.

Here's the example from the 2.2 reference manual:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Comment: Having used this exact configuration for years now, I can confirm it works just fine.  Just be sure to include monitoring of the proxy as well as the webserver - it does no good to have IIS up but Apache down.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct, and if you want SSL support:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/webmail.pem
```